# EnableResourceServer breaks oAuth2 authorization server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I implemented oAuth2 authorization server using Spring Boot version 1.5.2.RELEASE. The authorization server supports implicit flow. With the WebSecurityConfig below the login form (http://localhost:8200/login) works well.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JpaUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
    return userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() throws Exception {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean());
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return new ProviderManager(singletonList(authenticationProvider()));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/")
            .antMatchers("/docs/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger/**")
            .antMatchers("/token/**")
            .antMatchers("/v2/*")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and()
            .logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

I want resource server be a part of the same application. The purpose is I need a **/me** endpoint that will provide me details of logged in user and endpoints for managing users. But as soon as I add ResourceServerConfig annotated with EnableResourceServer below I start getting an error "Full authentication is required to access this resource" when I request http://localhost:8200/login.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    public static final String RESOURCE_ID = "proclaim-auth";

    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources
            .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
            .tokenServices(tokenServices);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/ **").authenticated();
    }
}
```

I suspect that resource server security chain precedes authorization server security chain. I tried to annotate WebSecurityConfig with annotation Order but it did not fix my problem:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please advise. 
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**
I added method configure(HttpSecurity http) into ResourceServerConfig and changed value of Order annotation to -1 on WebSecurityConfig. Now the security filted defined in WebSecurityConfig is applied and the one defined in ResourceServerConfig is ignored. So when I call **/me** endpoint with valid token I'm redirected to login page.

Answer (score 6):

The cause of the problem was wrong configuration of http security in the *ResourceServerConfig* class. The correct configuration is as follows:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**").and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

The *requestMatchers* will ensure that only requests on paths starting with "/api/" will be processed by this security chain. All other requests will be passed to the security chain defined in the *WebSecurityConfig* class. I was missing this in my config so all requests were processed by the *ResourceServerConfig* security chain and none request reached the *WebSecurityConfig* security chain.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, had the same issue.